# Finding minumum element in a stack in constant time

Tags: python, algorithm, stack

If I want to find a minimum element in a stack (integer key), in constant time then it can be done as following:

```
arr = [ 10, 7, 15, 12, 5 ] 

min_stack = []
main_stack = []

def get_min():
    if len(min_stack) < 1:
        return None
    return min_stack[-1]

def push(key):
    main_stack.append(key)
    if len(min_stack) < 1 or min_stack[-1] > key:
        min_stack.append(key)


def pop():
    key = main_stack.pop()
    min = get_min()
    if key == min:
        min_stack.pop()
    return key

for key in arr:
    push(key)
```

In the above solution it is possible to find out `min` value element in `O(1)` but it uses an auxiliary memory of size `n`.

Is there a way that It can be done without using a `n` size memory or say constant memory, by exploiting arithmetical properties of the integer key.

Comment: Do you just want to find the min element? You can just store the minimum element in a variable and update it everytime you push something.

Comment: as @Haris has mentioned, you can keep a reference to the minimum by updating it every time you change the stack -- e.g. if you push or pop something you check and maybe update.  However, this means that `pop` could end up running in O(N) time instead of O(1) for a traditional stack.  If you're Ok with using a heap to store everything in the stack, you might be able to bring that down to O(logN) but at the cost of memory.

Comment: What exactly would be the advantage over the good old `min()`?

Comment: @KlausD. -- `min` runs in O(N) time.  If you want to optimize the `find_min` function above other operations (maybe because it gets called more?) then it might be advantagous to keep that data around.

Comment: Is there any defined range for the values being put on the stack?  If they were all within the 32 bit range, then you could use 64 bit numbers to track the current min by bit-shifting.  Just a thought.

Comment: @mgilson I cannot keep a reference because once `pop` operation is performed in that case, will have to scan the whole stack `O(n)` to find out the next `key` where we need to point the reference.

Comment: @mgilson Even the most trivial approach of finding the minimum in a list is more efficient than the given example. On both CPU time and memory.

Comment: You could have a comprise solution, store the minimum value and a counter of elements with that value, when the counter reaches 0, make get_min recalculate the minimum .

Comment: @KlausD. This depends on the size of the stack.  If it's big enough, an O(1) approach will win over an O(n) approach.

Comment: What does `get_min` report after the following sequence of operations?  `push(10); push(7); push(7); pop(); print get_min()`

Comment: @ScottHunter `key`s are unique integers.

Comment: @anand That is documented where, exactly?

Comment: @SvenMarnach The given code loops over the elements and is therefore O(n).

Comment: @anand -- Yes, that was my point.  You can't get O(1) min and O(1) push and O(1) pop without keeping track of the previous minimas because otherwise, when you pop out a minima, you don't know what state to go back to without looking for it.  I have to admit, I didn't understand your solution at first, but I can't think of anything better since you do have O(1) operations for all of the 3 functions and your memory scales by the number of minima inserted... Not bad.

Comment: @KlausD. -- Where does the code loop over the elements?

Comment: I think you need `if len(min_stack) < 1 or min_stack[-1] >= key` in `push`.  Otherwise, if you put the same minima in twice, your state will be wrong after the first time you pop that minima out.

Comment: @mgilson Yes its a good solution, but I think exploiting some arithmetical properties of integer some mathematical relationship can be driven which can help me get rid of the second `min_stack`.

Comment: @sberry lets take your constraint as a precondition then please suggest how can we do bit shifting to find the next minima ?

Comment: @mgilson You can see it as you prefer: either you consider only the `get_min()` function the algorithm, then is does not do, what was decribed in the title. Or the whole program is the algorithm, then there are `n` push operations.

Comment: @KlausD. `get_min` is constant time though?

Comment: @KlausD. -- You can't build a stack of `N` elements in less than `N` time.  That much is assumed.  The question is how the various operations on the stack perform depending on the size of the stack.

Comment: @sberry It is O(1) but not constant time. Also it does not find a minimum value. It only returns the last item assuming it is the minimum.

Comment: @KlausD. How is it not constant time?  And it does not `find` a minimum, it `gets` a minimum because the last element in the `min_stack` IS the minimum.

Comment: @mgilson That is indeed a very good question, but here an otherone is asked. One with a assumption in the title that is not true. Precalculating the minimum and just retrieving it later does not allow you to say the retrieval happens in constant time, so finding the minimum happens in constant time.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't want to belabor this discussion, but `push() == constant time` and `get_min() == constant time` so the act of pushing and getting min is constant time.  Constant time refers to the change in time related to the size of the stack and in this implementation the execution time of those functions do not change with the stack's size.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is "no, it can't be done without using O(n) additional storage in the worst case".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it wasn't stated otherwise, I figured I would include what could be a solution if the range of integers being pushed onto the stack was limited to 32bit on a 64bit system.

I know these constraints may not be applicable, but I will leave this here in case it gives rise to other ideas.

**Note**  If the stack values were not restricted to being only integers then a tuple could be used as well in a similar fashion where a push of x would be a push of (min_thus_far, x) for example.

```
arr = [10, 7, 15, 12, 3, 21]

main_stack = []

def get_min():
    if len(main_stack) == 0:
        return None
    return main_stack[-1] >> 32

def push(key):
    current_min = get_min()
    if current_min:
        if key < current_min:
            current_min = key
    else:
        current_min = key
    main_stack.append(key + (current_min << 32))

def pop():
    key = main_stack.pop()
    return key & 0xFFFFFFFF

for key in arr:
    push(key)

def print_state():
    print(", ".join(str(x & 0xFFFFFFFF) for x in main_stack))
    print("min: %d" %(get_min(),))

for _ in arr:
    print_state()
    print "popped:", pop()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
10, 7, 15, 12, 3, 21
min: 3
popped: 21
10, 7, 15, 12, 3
min: 3
popped: 3
10, 7, 15, 12
min: 7
popped: 12
10, 7, 15
min: 7
popped: 15
10, 7
min: 7
popped: 7
10
min: 10
popped: 10
```

And here is a tuple version:

```
arr = [10, 7, 15, 12, 3, 21]

main_stack = []

def get_min():
    if len(main_stack) == 0:
        return None
    return main_stack[-1][0]

def push(key):
    current_min = get_min()
    if current_min:
        if key < current_min:
            current_min = key
    else:
        current_min = key
    main_stack.append((current_min, key))

def pop():
    key = main_stack.pop()
    return key[1]

for key in arr:
    push(key)

def print_state():
    print(", ".join(str(x[1]) for x in main_stack))
    print("min: %d" %(get_min(),))

for _ in arr:
    print_state()
    print "popped:", pop()
```

Comment: I think that I would argue that algorithmically, this is no different than OP's original solution.  It _is_ a clever way to save memory by storing the data in a slightly more compact way (enabled by the assumption that the elements in the list only take half the memory available to them), but it isn't a different algorithm :-)

Comment: I agree, the concept is entirely the same.  The answer was largely steered by the inquiry about "exploiting arithmetical properties of the integer key".  Though I would argue that it is easier to maintain a single stack than it is to maintain two, as the bug with duplicated minima already showed.

Comment: @sberry Its a clever technique and its definitely a step ahead of my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in `O(1)` without `O(n)` memory if you only want to store a single min value of all the pushed elements.

If you want to store a history of min elements, then there is no other way but to use a auxiliary data structure to hold them. In that case, using the stack is optimal since you can push/pop in `O(1)` time, which is the method you are using.

Aside: your code contains a tiny bug:

With your array `arr = [2, 2]`
 after 2 pushes, `min_stack = [2]`

When you pop the first time, `min_stack = []`
                      and `main_stack = [2]`
 So `get_min()` will return `None`, not `2`.

To fix it, change `push_key`:

```
 if len(min_stack) < 1 or min_stack[-1] >= key:
```

Comment: Not a bug if keys are unique (as author claims in comments).